# Apache Poi unable to read sheet names

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

We are experiencing a strange bug regarding reading of Excel sheets via Apache Poi. We are using version 5.0.

This code previously worked, however it has now stopped working on all of our production environments. It still works when testing locally so this is proving quite difficult to debug.

The issue is that we are getting null sheet names returned, so are unable to correctly load the required sheet.

```
try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(venueListFile))) {

        LOGGER.info("Found {} sheets", wb.getNumberOfSheets());

        // First setup venues
        Sheet venueSetUpSheet = wb.getSheet("Store Set Up");
        List<String> sheetNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Iterator<Sheet> it = wb.sheetIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            sheetNames.add(it.next().getSheetName());
        }

        if (venueSetUpSheet == null) {

            LOGGER.warn("Sheet 'Store Set Up' not found, available sheets: '" + String.join("','", sheetNames) + "'");
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("Found sheets: " + String.join("','", sheetNames) + "'");
```

Locally this returns:

```
Found 5 sheets
Found sheets: Store Set Up','Store Open Hours','Staff Setup','TV Configurations','Sheet3'
```

In production for the same Excel file it returns:

```
Found 5 sheets
Sheet 'Store Set Up' not found, available sheets: 'null','null','null','null','null'
```

It seems the file is read, and we have tested that the uploaded file on the server isn't corrupted. Is anyone aware of a known issue with Poi which would result in null sheet names?

Comment: Are the sheet names really `null` (I mean when you open the workbook manually and check the names with your human eyes, is there the expected name for every sheet) or does Apache POI just resolve them to `null`, like not being able to read the real name?

Comment: Manually checking the names in Excel matches that of the 'locally' ran version of our code.

Comment: When did this stop working - what did you change? Have you recently upgraded Apache POI or what have you done? If Apache POI was upgraded, see if downgrade helps and (if so) report a bug. If POI was not upgraded it is probably something else.

Comment: Are the POI versions in test and production environments the same ones?

Comment: Its unclear what has changed unfortunately. Java and POI versions are the same in both prod and dev. POI was upgraded however this was many months ago and the functionality has worked since then. I should also note the feature passes our automated tests too.

Answer (score 2):

`XSSFSheet` bases on the underlying `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet`. And  `XSSFSheet.getSheetName` simply returns `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet.getName`.

If that returns `null` instead of the name, then probably the wrong class `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet` is used. For `apache poi 5.0.0` it **must** be `CTSheet` from jar `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar` or `poi-ooxml-lite-5.0.0.jar`. It must **not** be from `ooxml-schemas-*.jar` or any `poi-ooxml-schemas-*.jar` like using lower versions of `apache poi`. Maybe some library in your productive environmwent ships or pulls any of the `ooxml-schemas-*.jar`? That is incompatible with `apache poi 5.0.0` then.

You can ask the `ClassLoader` where a special class (`org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet` in your case) came from on run time:

```
...
  ClassLoader classloader = org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet.class.getClassLoader();
  java.net.URL res = classloader.getResource("org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTSheet.class");
  String path = res.getPath();
  System.out.println("CTSheet came from " + path);
...
```

If that is not the `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar` or `poi-ooxml-lite-5.0.0.jar`,  you might get at least an idea which other library ships or pulls that class too.

If this doesn't help, please also check where `org.apache.xmlbeans.*` classes come from. `XmlBeans` are needed for `org.openxmlformats.schemas.*` classes.

```
...
  classloader = org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.class.getClassLoader();
  res = classloader.getResource("org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.class");
  path = res.getPath();
  System.out.println("XmlObject came from " + path);     
...
```

Using `apache poi 5.0.0`, this class **must** be from `xmlbeans-4.0.0.jar` it must **not** be from any other version of `XmlBeans`.

If all not helps, You can also check the same way whether `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet` really comes from `apache poi 5.0.0` (`poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar`). Maybe there are multiple `apache poi` versions in your productive environment. That's also not supported:

```
...
  classloader = org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.class.getClassLoader();
  res = classloader.getResource("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.class");
  path = res.getPath();
  System.out.println("XSSFSheet came from " + path);     
...
```

And at last, you could try getting the sheet name from underlying `CTSheet` object like so:

```
...
  try (Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./test.xlsx"));) {

   List<String> sheetNames = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Iterator<Sheet> it = wb.sheetIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Sheet sheet = it.next();
    if (sheet instanceof org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet) {
     java.lang.reflect.Field _sheet = org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.class.getDeclaredField("sheet");
     _sheet.setAccessible(true);
     org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet ctSheet = 
      (org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet)_sheet.get((org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet)sheet);
     org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.TypeStore store = ((org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase)ctSheet).get_store();
     System.out.println(store);
     org.apache.xmlbeans.SimpleValue target = (org.apache.xmlbeans.SimpleValue)store.find_attribute_user(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "name"));
     System.out.println(target.getStringValue());
    }
    sheetNames.add(sheet.getSheetName());
   }
  
   System.out.println(sheetNames);
  }
...
```

Does that work? Or is that throwing exceptions? If so, which?

And of course, please check all error logs for errors. Since `Office Open XML` stores data in `XML`, maybe there are problems while parsing `XML` using `Java`? But that should throw exceptions which should be logged somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for this. We have added the above code to output the path and have confirmed the correct classes are being used.

We have however found that rolling back to an earlier version of Java and Ubuntu the issue is resolved.

This version works: ```openjdk-8-jre-headless/now 8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~18.04 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~18.04]```

This one doesn't ```openjdk-8-jre-headless/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~18.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]```

Comment: I have added the additional logging you mentioned. This is the output: 

```CTSheet came from file:../lib/poi-ooxml-lite-5.0.0.jar!/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTSheet.class```
```XmlObject came from file../lib/xmlbeans-4.0.0.jar!/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.class```
```XSSFSheet came from file:.../lib/poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar!/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.class```

The output using your code example above also resulted in null values too.