# xlsx file content is corrupted after upgrading apache poi from 3.17 to 5.0.0 version

Tags: java, apache-poi

We are using the Apache POI library to generate Excel file and writing out the created workbook to **HttpServletResponse OutputStream** to download the file.

After upgrading Apache poi version from 3.17 to 5.0.0, Excel(xlsx) file content is being corrupted.

I am seeing the below statement in version 5.0.0 change list.

> Upgrade to ECMA-376 5th edition (transitional) schemas - expect API breaks when using XmlBeans directly some smaller changes are necessary when code is using the low-level CT... classes

Is it causing this issue? If yes, what changes need to done in my code?

Code:

```
final SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
final Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Catalogue");

final CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
final Font font = workbook.createFont();
            
font.setBold(true);
font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
style.setFont(font);
font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);

int rowCount = 0;
final Row header = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
final Cell c11 = header.createCell(0);
c11.setCellValue("Role");
c11.setCellStyle(style);

final Cell c12 = header.createCell(1);
c12.setCellValue("Business Process");
c12.setCellStyle(style);

int colcount=0;

final Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
row.createCell(colcount++).setCellValue(v.getRoleName());
row.createCell(colcount++).setCellValue(v.getBusinessProcess());

final OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
 
response.setContentType("application/xlsx");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "RoleCatalogues" + ".xlsx\"");
OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

workbook.write(outputStream));
response.flushBuffer();
workbook.dispose();
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFont.addNewFamily()Lorg/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTIntProperty;
```

[Question with same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67298679/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-openxmlformats-schemas-spreadsheetml-x2006-main)

### 3.17 POI dependencies

```
+- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.17:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.04:compile
```

### 5.0.0 POI dependencies

```
+- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.20:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.06:compile
```

Comment: In version 3.17 `workbook.write(outputStream)` had closed the `outputStream` after writing. Newer versions do not do this anymore. Try `outputStream.close()` after `workbook.write(outputStream)`.

Comment: @AxelRichter , apologies for late reply. I am getting an error and I know which not related to your suggestion. Please see the updated question for error.

Comment: @AxelRichter, I saw your answer to this error in another question, there is no ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar in the classpath.

Comment: Apache POI 5 needs `poi-ooxml-lite...jar` or `poi-ooxml-full...jar` in class path.

Comment: `workbook.write(outputStream)); outputStream.flush(); ...` is something too.

Comment: "there is no ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar in the classpath": According to the error there must be some old `ooxml-schemas` library in class path. Please do check. You can ask the `ClassLoader` where a special class (`org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFont` in your case) came from on run time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100632/apache-poi-unable-to-read-sheet-names/69102220#69102220.

Comment: @AxelRichter, You are correct, I checked with -verbose:class option. It is loading old version(3.17) of POI jars as well  even I did Maven update the project and Maven clean and build. I need to find the way how to stop old version jars from loading.

Comment: But, when I check under Maven Dependencies, old version jars are not appearing.

Comment: So it is a maven problem. Maybe apache poi 3.17 gets load because of  transitive dependencies automatically? What else libraries are you using which may have apache poi as a dependency? Maybe you can update those too?

Comment: updated question with both versions of POI dependencies. seems there are no transitive dependencies.

Comment: So the dependency apache poi 3.17 is in your POM? Why?

Comment: Apologies for confusion, apache poi 3.17 version is upgraded to 5.0.0(not in POM). Just want to show what were the dependencies with 3.17 and with 5.0.0 (before and after up-gradation).

Comment: @AxelRichter, it worked in direct Tomcat. I think issue with running Tomcat with Ecipse. Please  add your comments as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why the question had -1 rank this helped to see that someone else experience the issue, upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

As per comments from @AxelRichter, in version 3.17 workbook.write(outputStream) had closed the outputStream automatically after writing. In newer versions, it has to be closed manually after writing to workbook like below :

```
workbook.write(outputStream);
workbook.dispose();
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Hi,I am facing the same issue of corruption after the poi upgrade from 3.17 to poi 5.0.0.I could open the Excel file generated successfully,but when it is transfered to a third party like exchange server or Power BI,it is throwing error saying the excel is corrupted.Please note I am using the following code workbook.write(outputStream);
workbook.dispose();
outputStream.close(); But this is not resolving my issue.Any input will be helpful.

Comment: @Rakhi, Apologies for late reply as not seen your comment. did you see my code in the question above?  Please check for any differences like file format, workbook type, etc..

Comment: I already tried.. unfortunately it didn't work.While extracting the zip file I could see the standalone is set as no.But that was not the case with 3.17. Also the excel opens just fine.If I try to send it via a server it's identified as corrupted.