# Xlsx file content is corrupted after upgrading apache poi from 3.17 to 4.1.2/5.0.0 till 5.2.3 version

Tags: excel, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I am facing same issue as mentioned in [xlsx file content is corrupted after upgrading apache poi from 3.17 to 5.0.0 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624232/xlsx-file-content-is-corrupted-after-upgrading-apache-poi-from-3-17-to-5-0-0-ver).

I could open the Excel file generated successfully,but when it is transferred to a third party like exchange server or Power BI,it is throwing error saying the excel is corrupted.Please note I am using the following code

```
workbook.write(outputStream); 
workbook.dispose(); 
outputStream.close();
```

But this is not resolving my issue.

Another difference I observed is some of the xml files have "standalone=no" when extracting it to xml.This is tracked under **https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67396**

I am not sure if "standalone=no" is the reason for corruption.

Any input will be helpful.

Comment: This question needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be answerable. The linked question is not fully related as there was an `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` thrown which seems not in your case. And "I could open the Excel file generated successfully,but when it is transferred to a third party like exchange server or Power BI,it is throwing error saying the excel is corrupted." sounds as if the transfer to third party leads to the problem and not Apache POI.

Comment: @Axel Thanks for looking into this,you can say like transfering to third party application shows this error,but this was not the case with poi 3.17,it worked just fine.Only after upgrade we are facing the issue.If we download the file and save it manually ,then it get transfered through the third party application.The change we noticed between these two excel file is in the "standalone=no" in the xml files.

Comment: The `standalone` attribute in XML declaration should not lead to such problems as this only affects external markup declarations and there are none in Office Open XML. But this problem was disussed in your linked ASF Bugzilla – Bug 67396. Have you tried what suggested from PJ Fanning 2023-09-14 10:08:56 UTC?

Comment: Rakhi - you have not provided a reproducible use case. POI 5.2.4 was recently released and contains the small code change i mentioned in bug 67396. Have you tried that release? If it doesn't help, could you spend some time to provide a reproducible test case that can be investigated?

Comment: Unfortuanately poi 5.2.4  doesnot worked.
One thing I noticed is there is no where we could see "standalone=no" parameter in xml.
But the following xml files miss ,the standalone parameter,so as it is not present that will be treated as no i guess.So I unzipped the excel modified the xml files by adding "standalone = yes" parameter in xml ,zippped it back to excel and it started working
\filename\xl\sharedStrings.xml
\filename\xl\styles.xml
\filename\xl\workbook.xml
\filename\docProps\app.xml
\filename\xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml.Pls help me with the java files to modify to get this.